# Golf Club Proper Names

Tags: english-to-german

I am localizing some video games for the German language, but need to know the proper translations for a couple golf clubs.  I realize that each of these has a literal translation, but I was hoping someone could share the idiomatic names (as they would be called while golfing) in German.

The names I need are:

1. Driver (Found Fahrer but is this correct?)
2. Iron  (Found Eisen but I think this is speaking of the metal)
3. Putter (I think this one is literally putter in German)

Any clarification would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a golfer but I can give you this:

1. *Fahrer* is wrong; it refers to a person operating a vehicle. Anecdotally, *driver* is also translated as *Treiber* when referring to software. I thought of *Treiber* in golfing too but I don't believe that's right.
2. *Eisen* is correct, to the best of my untrained knowledge. *Ein Neuner-Eisen* is a colloquial term in German, and if that's not from golfing then I have no idea.
3. *Putter* is correct, when capitalized of course.

Answer (score 7):

The [German wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golfschl%C3%A4ger) names them

> Driver = Holz 1 or Driver
>
> Iron = Eisen
>
> Putter = Putter